# /usr/src full with header files, purge and autoremove not helping

Tags: apt, kernel, linux-headers

I have the issue with my /usr/src folder getting filled up with header files, and I didn't find a way to remove them. It is causing my disk very close to be totally out of free space:

```
# df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            481M     0  481M   0% /dev
tmpfs            99M  760K   98M   1% /run
/dev/xvda1      7.7G  7.3G  428M  95% /
tmpfs           492M   12K  492M   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs           492M     0  492M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs            99M     0   99M   0% /run/user/1000
```

Content of /usr/src:

```
# du -h -d1 /usr/src/ | sort -hr
4.0G    /usr/src/
115M    /usr/src/linux-aws-headers-4.15.0-1045
115M    /usr/src/linux-aws-headers-4.15.0-1044
115M    /usr/src/linux-aws-headers-4.15.0-1043
115M    /usr/src/linux-aws-headers-4.15.0-1041
115M    /usr/src/linux-aws-headers-4.15.0-1040
115M    /usr/src/linux-aws-headers-4.15.0-1039
:
and many more....
```

I tried running `autoremove` as suggested by many similar issues here, but it doesn't remove anything, and no error.

```
# sudo apt autoremove --purge
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 127 not upgraded.
```

What else can I do?

Update:
Running Ubuntu server (not desktop) with 8Gb disk space

OS version:

```
# lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS
Release:        18.04
Codename:       bionic
```

uname:

```
# uname -r
4.15.0-1032-aws
```

proc version:

```
# cat /proc/version
Linux version 4.15.0-1032-aws (buildd@lcy01-amd64-025) (gcc version 7.3.0 (Ubuntu 7.3.0-16ubuntu3)) #34-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jan 17 15:18:09 UTC 2019
```

Comment: I updated the question with OS info

Comment: yes, it is a server with 8GB disk space

Comment: Added the info. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you've upgraded your system or had an update with a new kernel, do a reboot before running below command

`dpkg -l 'linux-*' | sed '/^ii/!d;/'"$(uname -r | sed "s/\(.*\)-\([^0-9]\+\)/\1/")"'/d;s/^[^ ]* [^ ]* \([^ ]*\).*/\1/;/[0-9]/!d' | xargs sudo apt-get -y purge`

This will remove all the unused headers and images. When you reboot again, you will see only current kernel being listed in grub menu

I drop a reference [here](https://markmcb.com/2013/02/04/cleanup-unused-linux-kernels-in-ubuntu/) in case of if you wonder how that regex works

Comment: I didn't upgrade myself. Maybe there was something automatic? Can you check the info that I added and let me know if you think that still a reboot is necessary together with running your command?

Comment: Do a reboot. Does `/usr/src` contain only folders related to kernel versions?